# If `counsel-git` returns `Not in a Git repository`, can we run `find-file`?

Tags: find-file, counsel

I am using `counsel-git` to find files in my git repo. I have overwrite into default `find-file`'s keybinding.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'counsel-git)
```

If I am not in a `git-repo`, such as if I am in `~/`, I get following error message: `Not in a Git repository`. In that case as exception catch, can `find-file` be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here are the steps I took to find the answer:

1. check `counsel-git` source code and find the function `counsel-locate-git-root`
2. check `counsel-locate-git-root` again and find how counsel check if it's in a git repo

```lisp
(defun counsel-locate-git-root ()
  "Return the root of the Git repository containing the current buffer."
  (or (counsel--git-root)
      (error "Not in a Git repository")))
```

3. create a new function (or advice `counsel-git`):

```lisp
(defun counsel-git-or-find-file (&optional initial-input)
  "Call `counsel-git' if in git directory or `counsel-find-file'"
  (interactive)
  (if (counsel--git-root)
      (counsel-git initial-input)
    (counsel-find-file initial-input)))
```